# unity3d - can't show facebook profile image on the device ( simulator works perfect )

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am using Unity3d (c#) with facebook API. I try to show my profile image on the screen when I run it on the unity simulator everything works perfect and I got the image. but when I build a version and try it on a real device I get nothing.

I know that there is a issue with facebook CDN. the result of the request is 302 and WWW class can't handle with redirects so I did something like this (c# is a new language for me):

```
WWW www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;

    if( www.responseHeaders.ContainsKey( "LOCATION" ) ){

        var redirection = www.responseHeaders[ "LOCATION" ];

        WWW wwwRe = new WWW( redirection );
        yield return wwwRe;
        callback( wwwRe.texture, userID );

    }else{
        callback( www.texture, userID );
    }
```

please help me I loose my mind, why all my personal data comes on the device except the image that works perfect in unity. what I did wrong?

thanks.

**The solution:**

I tried many options to get profile image on the device nothing worked.
finally I upgrade Facebook SDK from 6.2.1 to 6.2.2 and Unity from 5.1 to 5.1.3 remove the app again from the device ( clear all the data ) and it works. it looks like Facebook's issue ( this is not the first time that they release SDK with bugs ).

I accept Umair's answer even that his code have some syntax issues, he really tried to help me and basically his answer is right.

I used this code to test my image:
( hope it will help for someone )

```
private void getMyProfileData(){

    // get profile image.
    FB.API( Util.GetPictureURL( "me", 128, 128 ), Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, callBackGetProfilePicture );
}

private void callBackGetProfilePicture( FBResult result ){

    // in case if there some error with the image.
    if( result.Error != null ){
        // call this method again
    }

    string ImageUrl = Util.DeserializePictureURLString( result.Text );  

    StartCoroutine(LoadPictureCoroutune( ImageUrl ));
}

IEnumerator LoadPictureCoroutune(string url){

    var profilePicRequest = new WWW( (string)url );
    yield return profilePicRequest;

    if( profilePicRequest.error == null)
    {
        Texture2D profilePic = profilePicRequest.texture;

            // my test image place
            Image profileImage = FBavatar.GetComponent<Image>(); 
            profileImage.sprite = UnityEngine.Sprite.Create( profilePic, new Rect(0,0,128,128), new Vector2( 0, 0 ));

    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Error While downloading Picture: " + profilePicRequest.error);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried it without the yield return's ?

Comment: Have you added debug prints to see if you are getting inside the ContainsKey if?

Comment: I can't debug it because in the simulator  it works and worked before I add "redirection" so it don't have "Location" key. I don't know how to debug on the device.

slapy - I will try without the yield but don't sure that it will works.

Comment: Is it IOS?  If so you can see Debug.Log via Xcode.

Comment: Add a Debug.Log and check what your location key has value . Add this log before yield return wwwRe; statement and after that check if(wwwRe.error){ Debug.Log(wwwRe.error.ToString();)} else if(wwwRe.isDone){callback( wwwRe.texture, userID );} this way you will know what is wrong with it.

Comment: I don't see my Debug.Log in the XCODE. any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use following Code to get Picture data from Facebook API:

   ```
   FB.API ("/v2.4/me/?fields=picture", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, RequestResponce);
   ```
2. In `RequestResponce` method:

   ```
   void RequestResponce(FBResult result)
   {
       Debug.Log("requestResponce(): " + result.text);
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Error))
       {
           Debug.Log("FB_API:ReadRequest:Failed:"+result.Error);
       }
       else
       {
           var data = SimpleJSON.JSON.Parse(result.Text);
           string url = data["picture"]["data"]["url"];
           StartCoroutine(LoadPictureCoroutune(url));
       }   
   }
   ```
3. ```
   IEnumerator LoadPictureCoroutune(string url)
   {
       var profilePicRequest = new WWW(url);

       Debug.Log("Going to Load Picture ");

       yield return profilePicRequest;

       if(profilePicRequest.error == null)
       {
           Texture2D profilePic = profilePicRequest.texture;

           if(profilePic != null)
           {
               // Use ProfilePic to wherever you want to.
               //SetPicture(ProfilePic);
           }
       }
       else
       {
           Debug.LogError("Error While downloading Picture: " + profilePicRequest.error);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: its not work for me, I don't get a picture only the white square that I put the my sprite on him ( I create a new sprite from Texture2d ). any ideas?

Comment: I find the solution ( in my question ), thank you for your help.